# javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found in docx4j Library in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, docx4j

**javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found in docx4j Library in Android**

I'm getting this error while importing docx4j library in Android
for manipulating checkbox value in .docx file or word file.
This error come's while reading word file.
thank you in advance.

Build.gradle file:

```
    dependencies {

     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
     implementation files('libs\\awt-bastardised-17v8.jar')
   //    implementation files('libs\\poishadow-all.jar')

  //    implementation files('libs\\jaxb-core-4.0.1.jar')
    //    implementation files('libs\\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar')
     //    implementation files('libs\\jaxb-impl-4.0.1.jar')
   //    implementation files('libs\\javassist-3.29.2-GA.jar')
      //    implementation files('libs\\jaxb-runtime-4.0.1.jar')

  //    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'



     implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
   implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0'
      implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0'
      implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j
        implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j', version: '6.1.2'
      implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-android'
     //    implementation group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0'
     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/stax/stax-api
     implementation group: 'stax', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0.1'

     implementation group: 'org.docx4j', name: 'docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext', version: '3.3.6'
      implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'


    //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-core-8.3.7.jar')
   //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-JAXB-Internal-8.3.7.jar')
 //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-openxml-objects-8.3.7.jar')
 //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-openxml-objects-pml-8.3.7.jar')
  //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-openxml-objects-sml-8.3.7.jar')

    //    implementation files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar')
   //    implementation files('libs/javax.xml.bind.jar')
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime
  //    implementation("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.0")

  //    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12'
 //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-core-11.4.8.jar')
   //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-openxml-objects-pml-11.4.8.jar')
    //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-openxml-objects-11.4.8.jar')
   //    implementation files('libs/docx4j-openxml-objects-sml-11.4.8.jar')
  //    implementation files('libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar')

  //    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core
  //    implementation("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.1")

     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress
      //    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.22")


   // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api
   //    implementation("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0")
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl
  //    implementation("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.0")

}
```

Kotlin Side:

```
 var resultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            try {
                data?.data?.let {
                    this.contentResolver?.openOutputStream(it)?.let {
                        this.contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)?.let { it2 ->
                            val wordPackage: WordprocessingMLPackage =  Docx4J.load(it2)
                            val mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.mainDocumentPart
                            val list = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w14:checkbox", false)
                            for (c in list) {
                                val element: JAXBElement<CTSdtCheckbox> = c as JAXBElement<CTSdtCheckbox>
                                val checkbox: CTSdtCheckbox = element.value
                                val list2 = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("../..//w:t", element, false)
                                val chkSymbol: Text = (list2[0] as JAXBElement<Text>).value
                                val checkedVal: org.docx4j.w14.CTOnOff? = checkbox.checked
                                if (checkedVal?.getVal()?.compareTo("0") == 0) {
                                    checkedVal.setVal("1")
                                    chkSymbol.value = String(Character.toChars(0x2612))
                                } else {
                                    checkedVal?.setVal("0")
                                    chkSymbol.value = String(Character.toChars(0x2610))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }


            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("tag", "Exception: " + e.message)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: docx4j for Android needs to be updated with a fresh release.  Until this is done you are pretty much on your own.  That said, you'll need to configure javax.xml.stream to use an implementation which is present on your class path.  I doubt docx4j specifies com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory; you will need to work out where that is coming from.

Comment: @JasonPlutext so there will be new update for docx4j library for android?

Comment: Eventually.....